# How do I verify a function with a parameter type (string,object) using moq

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit, moq

I have a event whose publish method has a signature as follows:

`publish((string moduleName,object moduleData) payload)`

I have a set up a `mockEventAggregator` and other necessary setups but I need to verify if it has been called once.

I am having a tough time trying to write the verify statement as the parameter seems a bit complex and confusing to me on how to implement it, as I'm not able to get the syntax right.

here's what I'm trying:

```
this.mockModuleEvent.Verify(x => x.Publish(It.IsAny<(string,object)>(), Times.Once));
```

Comment: do you have any errors with this code?

Comment: @vasily.sib It just says the Publish doesn't take two argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong brackets. Move one bracket from the end after `It.IsAny<(string,object)>()`

```
this.mockModuleEvent.Verify(x => x.Publish(It.IsAny<(string,object)>()), Times.Once);
```